# how do i display product information when they click on the product

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have been having issues figuring out how to display product information when the user clicks on the product.
So far i have the product page setup and a sort feature everything else i have tried breaks it.

```
<?php
        require_once('includes/database.php');
        $page_title = 'Classic Models | Products';
    ?>`enter code here`
    <?php include('includes/header.html.php'); ?>

     <?php 

    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'Name';


    $sql= "SELECT productName, productDescription, buyPrice
    FROM `Products`
    ORDER BY $sort";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    // get the sort order from the url


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        //echo var_dump($result);
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>
                <th><a href="?sort=ProductName">Product</a></th>
                <th>ProductDesription</th>
                <th><a href="?sort=BuyPrice">Price</a></th>
            </tr>';



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //'<pre>'. var_dump($row). '</pre>'; to show the loop worked
        //echo '<li>'. $row['productName'] . $row['productDescription'] . $row['buyPrice'] . '</li>' ; 

             //to get my products to show in a table.
    echo
                "<tr>
                  <td>{$row['productName']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['productDescription']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['buyPrice']}</td>



                </tr>";
        } 

        echo '</table>';

        }else{
            echo "Results not found";
    }




    //my footer 
    ?>
    <?php include('includes/footer.html.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks it" and _how_ do you want the details to be shown?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you want the product info to be displayed on the next page when they click on a product? If yes, you'd need an `<a>` tag under `<td>` (inside the `while` loop) and it could be linked to a new page. If you want to display product details on the same page, after the click, then you would probably want to use AJAX - see [this](https://programmerblog.net/jquery-ajax-get-example-php-mysql) example. Also, please consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) Prepared statements.

Comment: I want the product info to be displayed after they click on the product. When you say to put a <a> under the <td> do you mean inside of it or the line after between productName and productDescription.

Comment: Are there any errors or is the script completing but the information is missing? I'd also change the code `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){`

Comment: The table will display with out errors but I don't know how to add <a> to make it click able and when you click it have the product info show up